# R - dataframe - sum on group by columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

I tried the below codes and it can sum amount by columns month and variable.

```
test_dplyr = read.csv("test_dplyr.csv", header=TRUE)
test_dplyr

test_dplyr %>%
  group_by(month, variable) %>%
  summarise(a_sum=sum(amount))

> test_dplyr = read.csv("test_dplyr.csv", header=TRUE)
> test_dplyr
      month variable amount
1 1/11/2018        x   1000
2 1/11/2018        x   3000
3 1/12/2018        y   5000
4 1/12/2018        y   3000
> 
> test_dplyr %>%
+   group_by(month, variable) %>%
+   summarise(a_sum=sum(amount))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups: month [?]
  month     variable a_sum
  <fctr>    <fctr>   <int>
1 1/11/2018 x         4000
2 1/12/2018 y         8000
```

However, when i tried to do the same with my trade_test data, i couldn't get the expected output as with this working code. Appreciate if anyone can advise what's wrong that i couldn't get the same expected output as with above example.

Thank you.

```
trades_test = read.csv("trades_test.csv", header=TRUE)
trades_test

trades_test %>%
  group_by(Trade_date, Country_code) %>%
  summarise(a_sum=sum(Trade_value_local))

> trades_test = read.csv("trades_test.csv", header=TRUE)
> trades_test
     Sedol                   Description Trans_type Trade_date  Quantity Price_local CCY_local Trade_value_local Trade_type Country_code
1  B01NPJ1 TATA CONSULTANCY SERVICES LTD        BUY  11-Jan-18    38,164       40.88       INR         1,560,044    Buy New           IN
2  B012W42                 PUBLIC BK BHD        BUY  11-Jan-18   221,400        4.92       MYR         1,089,969   Buy More           MY
3  6288190            AU OPTRONICS CORP.        BUY  11-Jan-18 2,210,000        0.42       TWD           923,639    Buy New           TW
4  6491318            KINGBOARD CHEMICAL        BUY  11-Jan-18   138,500        5.54       HKD           767,200    Buy New           HK
5  6205122                   INFOSYS LTD        BUY  12-Jan-18    48,855       15.30       INR           747,548    Buy New           IN
6  6196152                 CITIC LIMITED       SELL  12-Jan-18   -81,000        1.41       HKD          -113,985  Sell Some           HK
7  6451055              HYUNDAI MOTOR CO       SELL  11-Jan-18      -786      147.42       KRW          -115,870   Sell All           KR
8  6868398              TELEKOM MALAYSIA       SELL  12-Jan-18   -83,100        1.47       MYR          -122,119  Sell Some           MY
9  6243586                      SATS LTD       SELL  11-Jan-18   -33,500        3.90       SGD          -130,632  Sell Some           SG
10 6253767               INDIAN OIL CORP       SELL  13-Jan-18   -21,571        6.06       INR          -130,824   Sell All           IN
> 
> trades_test %>%
+   group_by(Trade_date, Country_code) %>%
+   summarise(a_sum=sum(Trade_value_local))
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: <U+0091>sum<U+0092> not meaningful for factors.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `class(trades_test$Trade_value_local)` and you'll see that is a `factor`, not a numeric, and summing `factors` does not make sense. So you will have to convert it to a number first, by getting rid of the commas and then parsing to `numeric`. You could do that as follows:

```
trades_test %>%
  mutate(Trade_value_local = as.numeric(gsub(',','',Trade_value_local)))
  group_by(Trade_date, Country_code) %>%
  summarise(a_sum=sum(Trade_value_local))
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thank you very much in explaining the issue and advising the solution. I'm new to R, just started 2 weeks plus and trying to figure things around so it's really helpful to have these information.

Comment: Hi @YiWenEdwinAng, you are welcome, glad I could help. If you could [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark your issue as resolved, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: thank you for pointing out. I didn't know I have to accept the answer to mark the issue as being resolved. Have done this now.