# R: Sum specific columns grouped by a particular column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 
10    A    5    4    
10    A    6    3   
30    B    2    7   
45    C    5    1  
45    C    2    1
```

I want to sum columns 3 and 4 only grouped by Col2, such that my resulting data frame looks like

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 
10    A    11    7    
30    B    2     7   
45    C    7     2
```

Col1 is an identifier for Col2 so I want that to remain. Thanks

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212699/group-by-multiple-columns-and-sum-other-multiple-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - dataframe - sum on group by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353547/r-dataframe-sum-on-group-by-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by multiple columns and sum other multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212699/group-by-multiple-columns-and-sum-other-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Minimal reproducible example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c(10L, 10L, 30L, 45L, 45L),
                     Col2 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"), 
                     Col3 = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L),
                     Col4 = c(4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L)),
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

2.Solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
summarise(Col3 = sum(Col3),
          Col4 = sum(Col4))
```

Returns:

```
   Col1 Col2   Col3  Col4
  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1    10 A        11     7
2    30 B         2     7
3    45 C         7     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate`. As `Col1` is an *identifier* for `Col2` it could be used with `Col2` for grouping.

```
aggregate(.~Col1+Col2, df, sum)
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1   10    A   11    7
#2   30    B    2    7
#3   45    C    7    2
```

or you can use `rowsum`, `match` and `cbind`:

```
x <- rowsum(df[c("Col3","Col4")], df$Col2)
cbind(df[match(rownames(x), df$Col2), c("Col1","Col2")], x)
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1   10    A   11    7
#3   30    B    2    7
#4   45    C    7    2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to group by `Col2` and retain `Col1`, maybe you can use `aggregate` + `merge` from base R like below

```
dfout <- merge(unique(df[1:2]),aggregate(.~Col2,df[-1],sum))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Col2 Col1 Col3 Col4
1    A   10   11    7
2    B   30    2    7
3    C   45    7    2
```